# From scipy import fsolve ImportError: cannot import name 'fsolve' from 'scipy'

Tags: python, scipy

My code is as follows (I doubt you'll need it all, but I've provided everything):

```
import numpy
from scipy import fsolve
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Localize:

    receivers: list

    @staticmethod
    def equations(p, *times):

        x, y, z, t = p
        t0, t1, t2, t3, \
        ax, ay, az, \
        bx, by, bz, \
        cx, cy, cz, \
        dx, dy, dz, \
        c = times

        F = numpy.empty((4))

        F[0] = (ax - x) ** 2 + (ay - y) ** 2 \
             + (az - z) ** 2 - c(t0 - t)

        F[1] = (bx - x) ** 2 + (by - y) ** 2 \
             + (bz - z) ** 2 - c(t1 - t)

        F[2] = (cx - x) ** 2 + (cy - y) ** 2 \
             + (cz - z) ** 2 - c(t2 - t)

        F[3] = (dx - x) ** 2 + (dy - y) ** 2 \
             + (dz - z) ** 2 - c(t3 - t)

        return F

    @staticmethod
    def sanityCheck(times):
        # Check for valid input
        print('whoo')


    @staticmethod
    def find(self, times):

        times.append(self.receivers)

        initial = numpy.array([0,0,0,0])
        return fsolve(self.equations, initial, args = tuple(times))




local = Localize(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
local.find(1,2,3,4)
```

I verified that I do, in fact, have a functioning `SciPy` install by running:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.__version___
'1.5.3'
>>>
```

It's throwing the error:

> `From scipy import fsolve ImportError: cannot import name 'fsolve' from 'scipy'`

I've tried running this with the standard `Python` interpreter, as well as `PyCharm`, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import *fsolve* function from the *optimize* lib

Try out:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
```